# Is there a variable to inform Edit Action if I come from Create in mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Using mvc3, is there some variable to inform if I came from a Create to Edit action?

If the routing is used as well in a GET I want a certain behavior, otherwise if the CreateAction has been fired I want to open a different context Edit.

Failed first solution: Creating a extra Action Edit, fires: `The current request for action 'Edit' on controller type 'XController' is ambiguous between the two action methods`.

More important, is there a misinterpretation of MVC? Does this solution sound weird to anyone? I'm facing nice doubts with mvc. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have 2 Edit methods, they must have different method inputs to differentiate them.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    return View(db.GetWidget(id));
}

public ActionResult Edit(int id, string username)
{
    ViewBag.Username = username;
    return View(db.GetWidget(id));
}
```

Or, just make the method into one with an optional parameter

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, string username = "")
{
    ViewBag.Username = username;
    return View(db.GetWidget(id));
}
```

I would also recommend painting a method attribute such as [HttpGet], [HttpPost], etc.

Comment: Your first example wouldn't work. You'd receive an error calling Edit because there's no way to distinguish between which overload to call (if username is missing does it call the first overload or the second and pass null for a value)?

Comment: @Justin - look at the two code examples as completely separate - they could not exist together.

Comment: I wasn't talking about both examples, I was strictly referring to the two methods in your first example.

Comment: @JustinNiessner you are right, this example will not work. He should place different method attributes over each Edit action

Answer (score 1):

You can either add an optional parameter to your Edit action that flags whether or not you came from the Add action or you could create an entirely new action (with a unique name from Edit).

The former would look something like:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, bool? fromCreate = false)
{
    if(fromCreate)
    {
        // do your special processing
    }
}
```

And the latter, obviously, would be:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
}

public ActionResult EditNewlyCreated(int id)
{
}
```

Comment: This solution is great! The downside is the url that is being formed like this `Moo/Edit/76?fromCreate=True`. Is there some alternative to hide this fromCreate from url?

Answer (score 0):

In your create view or create controller action (no razor markup if its in the action):

```
@{ TempData["FromCreate"] = true; }
```

And then in your edit get action:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
 if( TempData.ContainsKey("FromCreate") )
 {
  var fromCreate = (bool)TempData["FromCreate"];
  TempData.Remove("FromCreate");
  if( fromCreate )
  {
   //insert logic
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have something linke this in MyView view:

```
          @model ModelClass

          @Html.BeginForm()
          {
               if(Model.Id > 0)
               {
                   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id);
               }

               ...
          }
```

And in controller:

```
     public ActionResult Edit(int id)
     {
           var model = modelRepository.GetById(id);
           Return View("MyView", model);
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
     {
           var model = modelRepository.GetById(id);
           TryUpdateModel(model)
           {
                modelRepository.Save(model);
           }
     }

     public ActionResult Create()
     {
           var model = new ModelClass();
           Return View("MyView", model);
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Create(ModelClass model)
     {
           ...
     }
```

In view, if Model.Id > 0 it means that we entered view using Edit action and when form posts, if there will be Id field in post parameters (hidden for id) then Edit(with HttpPost) will be called, else if there will not be Id parameter then Create action will be called